# All the jobs in chain are not executing in laravel task scheduling?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-jobs

I am trying to run three jobs in chain in laravel task scheduling in `kernel.php` but it is only executing first job and ignoring other two jobs.

`kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    // $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment)->everyMinute();
    // $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment)->everyMinute();
    // $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment)->everyMinute();

    $schedule->job((new \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment)->chain([
        new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment,
        new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment
    ]), 'mailbox')->everyMinute();


}
```

I want to run all the jobs in chain one by one.

Comment: Have you checked you're log? don't you have any error?

Comment: 1 -Have you checked you're log? =>didn't understand
2-  don't you have any error? => no error

Answer (score 0):

*Scheduling chained queuebale jobs* is not documented unfortunately but using `$schedule->call` and calling `withChain` statically may work:

```php
$schedule->call(function () {
    \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment::withChain([
        new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment,
        new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment
    ])->dispatch()->allOnQueue('mailbox');
})->everyMinute();
```

P.S: I haven't tested this, please let us know if it works.

Comment: it gives error :

In CallbackEvent.php line 38:

  Invalid scheduled callback event. Must be a string or callable.

Comment: yeah .. it gives me this message ```Running scheduled command: Closure```

Comment: @BilalArshad please don't forget to accept this answer if it works as expected.